# React - change state when props are changed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component, `AttributeSingleChoice` which I am calling like this:

Based on the new `props` I receive in it, I want to change its state, like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function() {
    var attributeTypes = this.selectAttributes();
    this.setState({
        singleChoiceAttributes: attributeTypes});
},

selectAttributes: function() {
    return this.props.classification.attributes.map(function (elem) {
        if(elem.attributeType == "A") {
            return {description: elem.description, name: elem.name}
        }
    }).filter(Boolean);
},
```

However, if I use `componentWillReceiveProps`, `state.props` will remember the old `props`, not the new ones, as I would like.

I tried using `componentWillUpdate` instead  but I can't set the state inside `componentWillUpdate`.

How can I change the state of the component based upon new props?

Answer (score 4):

The [`componentWillReceiveProps` hook](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops) is passed the new props as an argument.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
  newProps !== this.props
}
```

You can accept an alternate props with a parameter on your `selectAttributes` function.

```
selectAttributes: function(props) {
  // fallback to regular props if nothing passed
  props = props || this.props;

  return props.classification.attributes.map(function (elem) {
    // ...
  }).filter(Boolean);
}
```

Then pass the new props when they are available.

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(newProps) {
  var attributeTypes = this.selectAttributes(newProps);

  this.setState({
    singleChoiceAttributes: attributeTypes
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your componentwillrecieveprops header is incorrect.  You should take in a parameter for nextProps, which will contain the props being passed in.  Then set your state variable based off of the nextProps.  http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-specs.html#updating-componentwillreceiveprops

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass `nextProps` in to your function:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function( nextProps ) {
    var attributeTypes = this.selectAttributes( nextProps );
    this.setState({
        singleChoiceAttributes: attributeTypes});
},

selectAttributes: function( nextProps ) {
    var props = nextProps || this.props;
    return props.classification.attributes.map(function (elem) {
        if(elem.attributeType == "A") {
            return {description: elem.description, name: elem.name}
        }
    }).filter(Boolean);
},
```